# When declaring a variable: variable not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, variable-declaration

I have the code: `loading* loadingScreen = new loading(device);`

When I compile the program, the compiler complains that loading screen wasn't declared:

```
error: 'loadingScreen' was not declared in this scope
     loading* loadingScreen = new loading(device);
              ^
```

I'm unsure what's causing this. What I've tried:

- Rewriting it so that the constructor isn't run.
- Relocating the declaration to a different section of code.
- Making sure my classes are included correctly.

Here's my main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <future> // std::async, std::future
#include <chrono> // Millisecond timer
#include <pthread.h>
#include <loading.h>
#include <fps.h>

bool loading = false;

struct load_struct {
    irr::IrrlichtDevice *device;
    fps *fpsLevel;
};

void load(void * loadingStruct)
{
    loading = true;
    struct load_struct *args = (struct load_struct *) loadingStruct;

    loading = false;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    //Create display to optimal settings.
    irr::IrrlichtDevice *device = irr::createDevice(irr::video::EDT_NULL);
    irr::s32 depth = device->getVideoModeList()->getDesktopDepth();
    irr::core::dimension2d<irr::u32> resolution = device->getVideoModeList()->getDesktopResolution();
    device->drop();
    device = irr::createDevice(irr::video::EDT_OPENGL, resolution, depth, true, true, true, NULL); // TODO: Change last parameter
    if(device==NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create device! Do you have graphics drivers installed?" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Open data files
    device->getFileSystem()->addFileArchive("Resources",true,true,irr::io::EFAT_ZIP);

    device->getFileSystem()->addFileArchive("Video.tar");
    device->getFileSystem()->addFileArchive("Textures.tar");
    device->getFileSystem()->addFileArchive("Models.tar");
    device->getFileSystem()->addFileArchive("Audio.tar");

    //Load first room.
    loading* loadingScreen = new loading(device);
    fps *fpsLevel = new fps();
    pthread_t creationThread;
    struct load_struct loadingStruct;
    loadingStruct.device = device;
    loadingStruct.fpsLevel = fpsLevel;
    //pthread_create(creationThread,NULL,load,(void *)&loadingStruct); Fix me!
    while(loading==false)
    {
        loadingScreen->update();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000/60));
    }

    loadingScreen->kill();

    // Run first room.
    fpsLevel->run();

    //Clean up.
    device->drop();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my loading.h file:

```
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <string>
#ifndef LOADING_H
#define LOADING_H

class loading
{
public:
    loading(irr::IrrlichtDevice *device);
    void update();
    void kill();
protected:
    int slide;
    static const int SLIDES_AMOUNT = 60;
    const std::string FILENAME_TEMPLATE = "Loading_Screen/%.png";
    irr::video::ITexture* slides[SLIDES_AMOUNT];
};

#endif // LOADING_H
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more context about where the problematic line of code is? With just what you've provided here, I don't think there's enough information to help out.

Comment: I think that the error you're mentioning is the _second_ error, and it's a false positive caused by the _first_ error.  Namely that `loading` has no default constructor to be called by `new loading()`.

Comment: What happens when you go just ==> loading* loadingScreen = new loading;

Comment: I kinda figured that I'd be voted down here... But I really am stuck and I'm not seeing this issue anywhere else. This is the first error the compiler is mentioning, so it can't be a false positive. new loading() is actually supposed to be new loading(device); That was a typo on my part and will be corrected above. I will also attach my main class.

Comment: You have a `bool loading` and a `class loading`. Rename the `bool` at the top of main.cpp and wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the fact that you've got two different things called `loading`:

First, there's your `class loading`. But then, there's also the variable `bool loading`. So when you do:

```
loading* loadingScreen = new loading(device);
```

the compiler is confronted with an ambiguity and seems to prefer the variable `loading` over the type `loading` (I'm not an C++ pro and can't explain why this is the case; my guess is it's because the variable is the most "recent" definition of that name).

The fix is pretty easy: make the two names different. Since C++ is case-sensitive you should adopt the convention of starting class names with an uppercase letter: make that `class Loading` and `Loading* loadingScreen = new Loading(device);`.